# Condition for having different signs of 2nd degree polynomial

Tags: inequality, polynomials, proof-verification

Let's have the following polynomial:
$0.5x^2 + bx +c$

I want to check what the conditions are for having a positive root, and a negative root.

But I'm encountering a mistake which I cannot find.

I mark: $s = \sqrt{b^2-4ac}$

So the roots are: $R_{1,2}=-b \pm s $. (Since a=0.5)

The positive one will be $-b+s > 0$

The negative one will be $-b-s < 0$.

So I multiply the 2nd inequality by $-1$ and we get $b+s > 0$

I sum both inequalities and we get $2s>0$.

Therefore, $s>0$ is the condition for having 1 positive root, and 1 negative root, which means $b < -\sqrt{2c} $ and $b > \sqrt{2c}$ are the conditions.

But from checks I've performed, this is incorrect.

What algebraic mistake am I making here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your roots are real, the discriminant is positive, and $s$ is positive always, because it is the square root of a positivie number.

Take a look to the following. You need $-b+s>0$ and $-b-s<0$. This is $s>b$ and $b>-s$, in other words, $|b|<s$. Squaring, this is equivalent to $b^{2} < s^{2}$.

Now, remember that $s^{2}$ is just the discriminant, so $b^{2} < b^{2} - 4ac$, which is $4ac<0$. This is $2c<0$, or $c<0$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I understand you point, but I still don't understand why the algebra I've done with the inequalities gave me wrong results.

Comment: The problem is when you do de substitution $s=\sqrt{2c}$ in both inequalities. When passing $b$ to the other side, you must arrive to
$$
b>-\sqrt{2c}, \qquad b<\sqrt{2c}.
$$